# Placeholder not working with angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code:

```
<div class="form-group" [class.has-error]="!account.value && !account.pristine">
    <label class="sr-only" for="account">Account</label> <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.accountId" ngControl="account" #account="ngForm"> 
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Account</option>
    <option *ngFor="#acc of accounts" [value]="acc.id">{{acc.name}}</option> </select> 
</div>
```

in which the Placeholder is not working with ANGULAR2.

Please let me know if you require anything more?

Comment: Please, include the code as text instead of as a picture. It will make it easier for others to help you

Comment: Got fix. Check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if you will set up `this.accountId = "";` in your constructor.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6OUmXUlrCGfSCKqvU2dL?p=preview) here.

It was not working before, because ngModel you set in select. It waas trying to create data binding with values that dont exist.

Comment: Could you create plnkr?

Comment: plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/e4sXbUJRglpdSjjIFmep?p=preview . Place holder text (Account) not displaying in select.

Comment: Thank u, but accountId is an number in my model due to which i'm not able to set "" in my constructor. Is that anything can be done?

Comment: Yes, although select will only return you a string. You need to add onChange, to convert from string to number. However, this solves a problem of select and placeholder, which is original question. Please create new question for new question.

Comment: Also, @KannanMony, you should mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @uksz Could you please update my plunker with the onchange, so that I shall use it and mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I'm not able to see your changes. Y so? Anything I have to do? Could u please give the plunk link after u made the changes

Comment: sorry to bug u again. My problem is in my constructor.

this.accountId = "";  It throws this type error - type string not assignable to type number.  In my viewmodel, accountId is number

Comment: then set type of accountId to string|number

Answer (score 3):

you have not posted error you faced in your question. but still by assuming your use case i have created a plnkr for the
same.Try using this code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="account">Account</label>
    <select class="form-control" required #account (change)='selectValue(account.value)'>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Account</option>
        <option *ngFor="#acc of accounts" [value]="acc.id">{{acc.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here is plnkr link http://plnkr.co/edit/JFGhqxugZrSxyiWIzvzu?p=preview

Comment: Thank u. Could you please help me in this plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/e4sXbUJRglpdSjjIFmep?p=preview ?

Comment: whoops, I edited your answer, innstead of editing mine. Sorry!

Comment: @KannanMony your plnkr is working fine, whats the error here ? one thing more `disabled="disabled" selected="selected"` should be changed with `disabled selected` , and placeholder text i.e account is showing properly in my system (in both mozila and chrome latest versions)